# Selenium Driver cannot locate Absolute or Relative xpath 'selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: '

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

**Background:**
I'm writing a program to automatically send a message to certain contacts on my FB every few days.

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as UI
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

email = my_info['loginid']
password = my_info['password']


# defining xpath 
messanger_search_xpath = "//input[@type= 'text']"


# Open url Facebook with Chrome
test_driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=r'/Users/swapneel/Downloads/geckodriver')
test_driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/')

# defining an object that waits for a certain action to happen
wait = UI.WebDriverWait(test_driver, 20)


# loggin onto facebook
test_driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_k').click()  # to accept cookies
test_driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(email)
test_driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys(password)
test_driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()


# finding and writing the message
contacts = ["person1", "person2", "person3", "person4"]
message = "Beep boop boop, test"


wait.until(lambda test_driver: test_driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    messanger_search_xpath).send_keys(contacts[0]))
```

**Error:**
I can get past the login but can't actually input text into the search input on messenger. Usually a `NoSuchElementException` or a timeout error occurs.

**Attempted solutions:**
I've tried to use `time.sleep(10)` and also Selenium's `WebDriverWait` to eradicate the possibility of a race condition

I've tried using the absolute xpath `/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/span[1]/label/input`

and several variations of the relative xpath:

```
    '//input[@class="_58al _7tpc"]'
    '//label[@class="_58ak"]/input'
    '//input[@type= 'text']'
```

I've checked similar StackOverflow questions and attempted to use the answers but no luck.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks for taking the time to read this post

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 48, in <module>
    wait.until(lambda test_driver: test_driver.find_element_by_xpath(   File "/Users/swapneel/.local/share/virtualenvs/automatingMessenger-drOOJC49/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:

- the id of the input changes dynamically
- there's a cursed iframe that is different than your current focus
- you need to click on the input first (strange, I know, but it happens!) And then check that the id didn't change, that also happens.

have you tried using the Selenium IDE and recording the sequence of steps? That might also show what the problem is.

Comment: Recording the sequence of steps - That's a great idea. I shall run a few tests and report back what the issue was if I find it

Comment: For some reason, I can only finds things that are in the facebook Nav Bar. I can search there and find the xpath for that but once I try grab the path to anything below the Nav bar I have trouble. I've tried with the Selenium IDE and after following my log in process exactly the elements that are suggested still cannot be found when running my code.

Answer (score 0):

find the coordinates of input element.
After finding coordinates, move to required coordinates using Action chains library in python library, and then send your desired keys.